# How to upload file directly to s3 django

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I create a form field and uploading file using  that. I want those file to be uploaded directly to s3 without saving locally.
Here is the code

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('file upload',request.FILES['file']) 
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

now how can i upload `request.FILES['file']` via s3

I dont want to use djangostorages because i am already using that for another bucket and task

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your error message, but following steps may works...

1. import boto3
2. initialize S3 object
3. specify region and bucket
4. get uploaded file from form
5. put object to S3 with body and key(file name)

```py
import boto3
...
data = form.cleaned_data
if data['file'] != None:
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='your region name')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('your bucket name')
    bucket.put_object(Body=data['file'], Key=data['file'].name)
...
```

If it doesn't work, check your AWS S3 settings related your error messages(credentials, IAM role, default region, bucket policies and other settings).